# Can I change 1000 uF, 16 V for 1000 uF, 10 V?

Tags: capacitor, repair, electrolytic-capacitor, monitor

Few days ago my main monitor did not turned on. I opened it and discovered three capacitors, of 1000 uF/16 V each, in bad shape.
Since all stores here in my town are closed due the quarentine, I'm trying to find these capacitors in old electronics not working that I've found here in my house.

I did not found the three capacitors with the original values that my monitor board require but I've found three capacitors of 1000 uF/10 V each, and visually they look fine. Can I use them? Which are the effects of switching from 16 V to 10 V capacitors with the same capacitance?
I'll test them soon as my electronics tools that I bought arrive in my house (I'm a beginner with electronics and still studying the basics).

I've also have found capacitors of 470 uF/16 V, just in case this information be important.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Would you expect a 1 amp fuse to work in place of a 10 amp fuse?

Comment: Is it powered from 12 V by any chance? Your chances of not breaking anything should be much higher with two 470 uF/16 V in parallel to replace each 1000 uF/16 V.

Comment: If you ordered electronics tools, is there a reason you can't order appropriately rated replacement caps?

Comment: Why not parallel 6 pices of 470µF? then you almost got 1000µF.
if SMD stack them, if radial lead with long legs bend them and place them a bit higher if possible?

Comment: @AntonIngemarson 6? Wouldn't 2 caps give you 940uF?

Comment: @RonBeyer Ofc but with some luck considering most capacitors usually have +/-20% or more in tolerance 940µF will be higher than 800µF so long the combined 470µF capacitors is over 800µF

If possible you could actually search it up, and measure the good caps

Comment: The monitor stoped working much after I order the tools. I can order the capacitors but just doesn't compensate buy only this for the shipping price.
I'll try to build the wiring diagram you both suggested here just to understand how I could theoretically solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The 16V might be for reason. If the actual voltage rail is below 10V it might be fine. If it is over 10V then it is not fine. But capacitors have also other properties than capacitance and voltage. For example ESR. If the old caps were low-ESR caps, and you put standard caps there, it is also not fine. It completely depends on what the original capacitors were doing in the circuit.

Comment: Nice to know it. In fact, some of the capacitors of other capacitances avaible on other boards are low ESR, while the capacitors on the monitor board, aren't. Didn't know it was that important. Thanks.